# Reply button in Email MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MailerBase in MVC 4.0 to send the Email. This is working fine perfectly. My question is: When I send the Email, I want  to add a button, so that when user click on this button, will send reply of the email without clicking the default button like Reply in yahoo/GMail mails.

Is it possible in .NET MVC4 ?

Comment: Include a mailto link that points to your email address?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: In MVC4 I am using the MailerBase to send mails. In my email template i want to keep a button that will reply back to the email address that sent the email, but using the button in the email and not using the Reply/Forward buttons that we can already see in the Yahoo/GMail. Is it possible? In case of confusion while understanding the question, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

This question is not specifically related to ASP.NET MVC. The closest you could get is to include an anchor with the `mailto:` inside the body of the message:

```
<a href="mailto:your_email@your_domain.com?Subject=Hello%20World" target="_top">Reply</a>
```

If the user clicks on this link it will be opened with the default email client that he has associated on his computer.

This being said, doing such things is a bad idea. People normally know how to reply to emails in their favorite email client. Another reason why this is a bad idea is that most email clients will simply block links in email messages especially if they are not from trusted sources. So even if you include such link it will be useless.

Comment: This will simply send a new mail. This will not be a reply of the send mail. My question is: I have a button in email template. When I send the email, the template contains the button can be seen in the sent mail. Now, user presses the Reply button. in your case, it will generate a new email not the reply of that email.

Comment: That's the closest you could do.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid generating the new email and only generate the Reply ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I needed a reply email. The above code will generate a new email. ok. Let me explain. In case I click the Compose button that we see normally in the GMail or Yahoo. It send a mail. That's a not a reply or Forward. Correct? Now, when I receive the email, in case I want to reply that we have Reply button in GMail. My question is instead of composing the email from the scratch(as done in your code), I need to send a reply bu keeping some button in the send email. Please let me know in case of any confusion. Thank Yo

Comment: Sorry, but I am afraid that what you are trying to achieve is not possible.